# Splitting a Large Data File in R using Strsplit and R Connection

Tags: r, strsplit

Hi I am trying to read in a large data file into R. It is a tab delimited file, however the first two columns are filled with multiple pieces of data separated by a "|". The file looks like:

```
A|1   B|2   0.5  0.4
C|3   D|4   0.9  1
```

I only care about the first values in both the first and second columns as well as the third and fourth column. In the end I want to end up with a vectors for each line that look like:

```
A  B  0.5  0.4
```

I am using a connection to read in the file:

```
con <- file("inputfile.txt", open = "r")
lines <- readLines(con)
```

which gives me:

```
lines[1]
[1] "A|1\tB|2/t0.5\t0.4"
```

then I am using strsplit to split the tab delimited file:

```
linessplit <- strsplit(lines, split="\t")
```

which gives me:

```
linessplit[1]
[1] "A|1" "B|2" 
[3] "0.5" "0.4"
```

When I try the following to split "A|1" into "A" "1":

```
line1 <- linessplit[1]
l1 <- strsplit(line1[1], split = "|")
```

I get:

```
"Error in strsplit(line1[1], split = "|") : non-character argument"
```

Does anyone have a way in which I can fix this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Since you provided an approach I explain the errors in the code even though for your problem maybe you have to consider another approach.
Anyway putting aside personal tastes about code, the problems are:

1. you have to extract the first element of the list with double brackets
   `line1[[1]]`
2. the `split` argument accepts regular
   expressions. If you supply `|` which is a metacharacter, it won't be
   read *as is*. You must escape it with `\\|` or (as suggested by @nongkrong) you have to use the `fixed = T` argument that allows you to match strings exactly *as is* (say, without their meaning as a meta characters).

The final code is `l1 <- strsplit(line1[[1]], split = "\\|")`

as a final personal consideration, you might take into considerations an `lapply` solution:

```
lapply(linessplit, strsplit, split = "|", fixed = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to your original problem, says

split lines

```
"A|1\tB|2\t0.5\t0.4"
"C|3\tD|4\t0.9\t1"
```

into

```
A  B  0.5  0.4
C  D  0.9  1
```

Below is my code:

```
lines <- c("A|1\tB|2\t0.5\t0.4", "C|3\tD|4\t0.9\t1", "E|5\tF|6\t0.7\t0.2")
lines

library(reshape2)
linessplit <- colsplit(lines, pattern="\t", names=c(1:4))
linessplit

split_n_select <- function(x, sel=c(1), pat="\\|", nam=c(1:2)){
  tmp <- t(colsplit(x, pattern=pat, names=nam))
  tmp[sel,]
}

linessplit2 <- sapply(linessplit, split_n_select)
linessplit2
```

That's break it down:

1. Read original data into *lines*

   ```
   lines <- c("A|1\tB|2\t0.5\t0.4", "C|3\tD|4\t0.9\t1", "E|5\tF|6\t0.7\t0.2")
   lines
   ```

   Results:

   ```
    [1] "A|1\tB|2\t0.5\t0.4" "C|3\tD|4\t0.9\t1"   "E|5\tF|6\t0.7\t0.2"
   ```
2. Load **reshape2** library to import function *colsplit*, then use it with pattern "\t" to split lines into 4 columns named 1,2,3,4.

   ```
   library(reshape2)
   linessplit <- colsplit(lines, pattern="\t", names=c(1,2,3,4))
   linessplit
   ```

   Results:

   ```
       1   2   3   4
   1 A|1 B|2 0.5 0.4
   2 C|3 D|4 0.9 1.0
   3 E|5 F|6 0.7 0.2
   ```
3. That's make a function to take a row, split into rows and select the row we want.

   Take the first row of linessplit into *colsplit*

   ```
   tmp <- colsplit(linessplit[1,], pattern="\\|", names=c(1:2))
   tmp
   ```

   Results:

   ```
       1  2
   1   A  1
   2   B  2
   3 0.5 NA
   4 0.4 NA
   ```

   Take transpose

   ```
   tmp <- t(colsplit(linessplit[1,], pattern="\\|", names=c(1:2)))
   tmp
   ```

   Results:

   ```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4] 
   1 "A"  "B"  "0.5" "0.4"
   2 " 1" " 2" NA    NA
   ```

   Select first row:

   ```
   tmp[1,]
   ```

   Results:

   ```
   [1] "A"   "B"   "0.5" "0.4"
   ```

   Make above steps a function *split_n_select*:

   ```
   split_n_select <- function(x, sel=c(1), pat="\\|", nam=c(1:2)){
     tmp <- t(colsplit(x, pattern=pat, names=nam))
     tmp[sel,]
   }
   ```
4. Use sapply to apply function *split_n_select* to each row in linessplit

   ```
   linessplit2 <- sapply(linessplit, split_n_select)
   linessplit2
   ```

   Results:

   ```
        1   2   3     4    
   [1,] "A" "B" "0.5" "0.4"
   [2,] "C" "D" "0.9" "1"  
   [3,] "E" "F" "0.7" "0.2"
   ```
5. You can also select the second row by adding *sel=c(2)*

   ```
   linessplit2 <- sapply(linessplit, split_n_select, sel=c(2))
   linessplit2
   ```

   Results:

   ```
        1   2   3  4 
   [1,] "1" "2" NA NA
   [2,] "3" "4" NA NA
   [3,] "5" "6" NA NA
   ```

Answer (score -2):

Change

```
line1 <- linessplit[1]
l1 <- strsplit(line1[1], split = "|")
```

to

```
line1 <- linessplit[1]
l1 <- strsplit(line1[1], split = "[|]") #i added square brackets
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When answering, consider adding justification for what you're recommending like why it should work, any relevant documentation links etc. When you write a rigorous answer like that, you may realise when what you're recommending doesn't work :)